# What is the keyboard shortcut for "Open With" in Finder?

Tags: keyboard, finder, shortcut

How can I open a file with an application, other than the default, using a keyboard shortcut? I don’t want to change the default application for the filetype.

E.g. sometimes I want to open a .html file using an editor instead of a browser.

Comment: The closest I get is if I know the name of the app, I press `Cmd Shift /`, then start typing the name, and use the down arrow to select `Open With > App`

Comment: There is a direct and super easy solution to this. Check my answer.Please accept it as answer if it serves your need.

Answer (score 19):

The best solution for me:

1. Select file you want to open
2. Press <kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> (opens up the mighty Help search)
3. Then start to type a name of app you want to open
4. Use arrow keys to select right menu item
5. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
6. Done!

For example I want to open HTML-file with Sublime Text instead of Chrome. 
I navigate to this file, press shortcut, type in "su", press down-arrow and press enter!

[image]

Comment: I had to first navigate to the Finder's actual "File > Open With…" menu item, and allow the submenu to populate before this would work, but once I did that it works as described.

Comment: A similar alternate approach to this solution: Ctrl + F2 will highlight the Apple menu, which you can then navigate with using the arrow keys to choose the desired item under "File > Open > Open With…", and typing letters allows you to jump to menu names faster.

Answer (score 7):

I'm afraid there's no such shortcut. You can, though, create your own.

To do so just:

1. Go to **System Preferences / Keyboard / Keyboard Shortcuts / Applications**.
2. Click the **+** button.
3. Choose **Finder**, from the drop-down list.
4. On the *menu title* field add **the exact name** of the menu bar item. It this case it should be `Other...` instead of `Open with`.
5. Pick your keyboard shortcut and click **Add**.

You'll be able to test the shortcut right away. Just mind the **Open always with** option!

Comment: I dont think this works. I just tried and looks like Finder confuses Open With and `Always Open With` (10.7.5): [The keyboard shortcut pref](http://imgur.com/CoPWC) and  [the error message](http://imgur.com/Skmni)

Comment: Also, as a side effect of adding the shortcut, the `Open With` context menu item (ctrl+click) becomes `Always Open With` whenever the keyboard shortcut is mapped: [Before](http://imgur.com/6e9ha) and [After](http://imgur.com/NJ2y8)

Comment: @Nivas Indeed, that's why you have to write `Other...` instead of `Open with...`. [This](http://imgur.com/hSZz2) is how it should look like. It's in Spanish, but you see my point.

Comment: @Nivas And [here](http://imgur.com/nbBIx) the preferences panel, in case I didn't make myself clear enough.

Comment: Ah... I did not know that. `Other...` does work. (It does amaze the programmer in me though that there is an implicit assumption that the menu items should have unique names. What if another submenu has an `Other`? But that is beyond this question...)

Comment: This is not working on 10.10 the menu Othe… get the shortcut but does not respond

Comment: I made an Automator service that works http://www.markosx.com/thecocoaquest/finders-open-in-other-shortcut-that-works-in-mavericks/

Comment: @markhunte Why don't you post it as a proper answer?

Comment: @Thecafremo done.

Comment: IT WORKS!! YAY!!! On macos 10.12 (sierra) at least

Answer (score 5):

If you frequently open a file in a specific app (other than the default app), you can set a keyboard shortcut for doing it. This is super easy.

Let's say you want to open a file in Sublime Text whenever you press <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> **after selecting the file**.

1. Go to **System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts** *(tab)* **> App Shortcuts** *(option in left sidebar)*.
2. Create new shorctut by clicking/tapping on **+**.
3. Select **Finder** as **Application**.
4. Set **Menu Title** as **Sublime Text** (or **Sublime Text.app**, depending on your settings).
5. Set **Keyboard Shortcut** as <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>. It will be shown  as **^S**. Or you can use any other shortcut which you prefer.
6. Click/Tap on **Add**.

Now you can simply select the file and press <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to open the file in Sublime Text.

Comment: Thank you, @Safwan - excellent tip. I had to change the Menu Title to "Sublime Text.app" (without quotes) for it to work; filename extensions were set to display in Finder, so the entry under File > Open With included the extension.

Comment: After testing in 10.14.6 a bit more, it turns out that Finder responds to the keyboard shortcut only sporadically; rebuilding the Launch Services database to fix the slow "Fetching..." bug or changing the shortcut to another combination did not resolve.

Comment: Here's what ended up working for my use case: assigning a keyboard shortcut to one of the Finder Services ("Open File in CotEditor") instead of relying on "Open With", "Other...", etc. A [custom service shortcut](https://gist.github.com/idleberg/fc0df222e1df258d525d704042d72582) can also be created for apps that don't offer one (e.g., Sublime Text).

Comment: This is smart. Note that, like Miles Wolbe, I had to add “.app” for it to work for me (I’ve added this to the text of the answer). For the curious, this is how this approach works: the “Open with” submenu for the Finder’s contextual menu lists possible apps. Since they are shown here, these app names are menu items that can be called using custom shortcuts set using System Preferences.

Answer (score 2):

As requested , here is a capture of [[my blog]](http://www.markosx.com/thecocoaquest/finders-open-in-other-shortcut-that-works-in-mavericks/) post for an Automator Service that works for me in Yosemite .

[image]

Code for Applescript in step **2**

```
on run {input, parameters}

    tell current application to activate


end run
```

Code for Applescript in step **5**

```
on run {input, parameters}
    set theApp to (POSIX path of (item 1 of input))
    repeat with i from 2 to number of items in input
        set this_item to item i of input
        tell application theApp to open this_item
    end repeat
    tell application theApp to activate
end run
```

---

After Saving the Automator Service go to  System Prefs.  and add your shortcut to it.

[image]

Comment: Glad I followed through with this one, just had to discover some 'right'-clicking needed for your orange dotted-line instruction (at least that's how I got through it.) Thanks for posting

Answer (score 0):

I have used [FastScripts](http://www.red-sweater.com/fastscripts/) to assign a shortcut to this script. It can also be used to select the open recent menus in other applications.

```
try
    set l to {"Open With", "Open Recent", "Open Recent File", "Recent Projects", "Open Recent Set"}
    tell application "System Events" to tell (process 1 where it is frontmost)
        tell menu bar item 3 of menu bar 1
            click
            repeat with x in l
                try
                    menu item x of menu 1
                    click menu item x of menu 1
                    exit repeat
                end try
            end repeat
        end tell
    end tell
end try
```

I also used scripts like in 10.6 and earlier:

```
try
    tell application "Finder"
        open (get selection) using path to application "TextMate"
    end tell
end try
```

There is a [bug](http://www.openradar.me/9406282) that makes them unusable in 10.7 and 10.8 though. It could be avoided by focusing another application at the start, but it results in a visual glitch.

You could also use [Automator services](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/66384/choosing-between-opening-a-file-with-primary-or-secondary-program-with-a-shortcu/), but there is another bug where the shortcuts for services don't always work until the services menu has been shown from the menu bar.

Comment: The shorter solution (FastScripts) works flawlessly in 10.11, at least for opening file in Emacs.

Answer (score 0):

My favorite solution is using Better Touch Tool, a free app. 
For this to work you need to have Full Keyboard Access turned on (in system preferences - keyboard preferences - shortcuts), so that ctrl-f2 will access the menu bar.

Then use BTT to configure your short-cut (I use ctrl-alt-cmd-O) to do ctrl-f2, then attach addtional actions (10 times: two right arrows, then 7 down, then one right). 
When typing your shortcut you will get to the same submenu as you would get using the right mouse click and 'open with'.

Note that ctrl-f2 may not be displayed in BTT when you type it, but it does after you do 'attach additional action'.

Answer (score -1):

Right click on the file > press h key > use arrow keys to navigate

Comment: This does not appear to work on OS X 10.9. Do you have any third party utilities installed that may be providing this functionality?